# Execute dynamic select query stored in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have stored `select` statements in a table column named RuleSql. In the future the table size will go large, so how can I execute all the stored select statements at the same time to get the result?

I have used:

```
EXEC sp_executesql
```

But it is not helpful for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very poor practice storing SQL code in a table. Have you looked at views, stored procedures or inline table-valued functions?

Anyway, to execute the stored SQL in a table you would do something like this....

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT TOP 1 @Sql = RuleSql
FROM TableName  --<-- table where sql is stored   
WHERE <Some Condition>

Exec sp_executesql @Sql
```

Just saw your edit. To execute all the queries at once you would use a cursor something like.....

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);


DECLARE Cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT  RuleSql
FROM TableName  --<-- table where sql is stored   


OPEN Cur

  FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Sql 

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
     Exec sp_executesql @Sql
     FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Sql 
END

CLOSE Cur
DEALLOCATE Cur;
```

Comment: This is requirement of application  to store sql statement into the table, this is dynamic select statement generated by application user from UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this same information but for the whole database (all tables of a database) and create a table wit results you can use followin

Comment: Hi casjorge. Followin what exactly?